# How to use MEF IsMultiple property

Tags: .net-4.0, mef

**Background:**  I'm attempting to us MEF to import two assemblies implementing IFoo.  To do so, unsurprisingly, I'm using [ImportMany] to import all giving me an IEnumerable>.  Then my consuming logic determines which of the imported assembly to use based on MetaData "Bar".

Each exporter is decorated with an ExportMetadata attribute.  This works fine when I have:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[ExportMetadata("Bar", "Hello")]
public class Hello : IFoo
{...}

[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[ExportMetadata("Bar", "World")]
public class World: IFoo
{...}
```

That is, my IEnumerable has two IFoos.

I want to define one as a default so if there is no need for "Hello" nor "World", I'll look for the one with "Default" as my Bar metadata.  I have attempted to do this using IsMultiple property like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[ExportMetadata("Bar", "Hello", IsMultiple = true)]
[ExportMetadata("Bar", "Default", IsMultiple = true)]
public class Hello : IFoo
{...}
```

**Problem:**  When I add the IsMultiple property and second attribute, the Hello class is no longer pulled into the resulting IEnumerable.

**Question:**  How do I tag a class for MEF with a second/default designation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expose multiple completely separate exports on a class like this, the best approach is to use multiple 'property exports' that in this case return 'this'.

```
class Hello: IFoo
{
    [Export, ExportMetadata(...)]
    public IFoo Bar { get { return this; } }

    [Export, ExportMetadata(...)]
    public IFoo Default { get { return this; } }
}
```